# Back to previous page without reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, reload

I would like to return user form detail page to previous page (list of users).

If i try to click to back button in the browser, app request is processed via app router and list page is reloaded again.

I would like to add back button into detail which return user to previous page without reload method in ng-init.

**Is it possible? And if yes, how to easily solve it?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

In your app.config enable HTML5 push state through

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

(Make sure to inject $locationProvider)

Now you can watch the location change events and can update your view accordingly using 
 - $locationChangeStart 
 - $locationChangeSuccess

Also you can change the route using $location.path(), $location.url() on your back button.

View this link for reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location